# Is there a way to determine if a particular route is in your Navigator back stack?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an application that has several screens with associated routes such as 'SplashRoute', 'LoginRoute' and 'HomeRoute', 'DetailRoute'. With various types of entry points into the application, most of the routes are optional, so it makes using Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil for a route difficult, as the route may or may not be in the back stack. I'd like to be able to determine if a particular route is in the back stack or not.  How would you read the Navigator back stack to determine if a previously used route exists in the back stack, an example would be helpful.

Comment: You can use https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html to maintain your own history stack. I think there is an open issue about making the routers history available.

Comment: Is there a way to implement Navigator isActive?

Comment: I believe so . .

Comment: Do you know of an example?